# System.Xml or System.Linq to check if the attributes count are in order

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this example xml:

```
<tr:secmain>
    <fn:footnote num ="1">
    <fn:footnote num ="2">
    <fn:footnote num ="3">
    <fn:footnote num ="3">
    <fn:footnote num ="5">
</tr:secmain>
<tr:secmain>
    <fn:footnote num ="1">
    <fn:footnote num ="2">
    <fn:footnote num ="3">
    <fn:footnote num ="4">
    <fn:footnote num ="6">
</tr:secmain>
```

For every element  I need to check if all footnotes are in order and if errors are found I need to check where this line appears. In the example the line errors are Line 5 and Line 13.

Right now I am currently checking for errors using Linq, by extracting all the the numbers to other textfile and check the incorrect lines with this method:

```
int[] IncorrectLines(string filename)
{
    // Parse the file into an array of ints, 10* each version number.
    var ints = File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Select(s => (int)(10 * decimal.Parse(s))).ToArray();
    // Pair each number up with the previous one.
    var pairs = ints
    .Zip(ints.Skip(1), (p, c) => new { Current = c, Previous = p });
    // Include the line numbers
    var withLineNos = pairs
    .Select((pair, index) => new { Pair = pair, LineNo = index + 2 });
    // Only keep incorrect lines
    var incorrect = withLineNos.Where(o =>
    o.Pair.Current - 1 != o.Pair.Previous && // not a simple increment
    o.Pair.Current % 10 != 0);               // not a whole new version
    // Return the line numbers; could return (double)o.Pair.Current / 10 instead.
    return incorrect.Select(o => o.LineNo).ToArray();
}
```

But I am having trouble now, because I need to check the sequence for every tr:secmain

Thanks for all of your advice. :)

edit:

The footnotes can be in this order: (Just a sample)

```
1
2
    2.1
    2.2
    2.3
3
    3.1
    3.2
    3.3
    3.4
    3.5
    3.7
4
5

etc.
```

Comment: Do you need to check if they are in order, or if the next footnote is exactly 1 more than the previous one? Technically `2, 3, 4, 6` and `2, 3, 3` are in order.

Comment: How does your sample correlates to xml above?

Answer (score 0):

Don't check the attributes for their order, just order them such as:

```
string xml =
@"<tr>
    <footnote num =""5""/>
    <footnote num =""3""/>
    <footnote num =""2""/>
    <footnote num =""3""/>
    <footnote num =""1""/>
</tr>
";


var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var results =
xdoc.Element("tr")
    .Descendants()
    .OrderBy (x => x.FirstAttribute.Value);

results.ToList()
       .ForEach(element => Console.WriteLine (element));/* Ouputs:

<footnote num="1" />
<footnote num="2" />
<footnote num="3" />
<footnote num="3" />
<footnote num="5" />

*/
```